# Error "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" when adding a reference to a .Net 4 project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, reference

I get an Error "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" when adding a .dll reference to a project in Visual Studio 2010.

The weird thing is, if I make a local copy of the .dll, and reference it locally it's fine. However, if I try and reference it from our shared resources server (\server\release\Common\Payment\v1.0\Libr\23\PaymentServices.dll) - It gives me the above error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crappy error code.  Try it on another machine to isolate the cause.

Comment: Hi, I have tried it on my colleague's machine, with no problems. Could it be a bad VS installation? Has anyone come across this problem, or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a seemingly similar problem with the same error message in a VS2010 that was caused by an inconsistent filestructure ie. the project was referencing files that wasn't there or as the project would expect them.

Make sure the files are accessable/available.

Answer (score 0):

I unloaded the project and reloaded it. After doing this, I could add the project as a reference to others.